# setText method not working?

Tags: java, multithreading, button, jbutton, settext

so I'm developing a multiplayer tic tac toe game in Java and I'm currently establishing a working server/client connection that will change a button's text(EX: [ ] changes to [ X ] when clicked). So as of right now I'm only working on the server GUI and the client has to type in x or o to change the servers button. I created a testing class with one button I want to change. I'm using breezyswing for anyone familiar but I don't believe my problem has anything to do with it. The class is as follows(please don't mind the improper formatting, it got messed up copying it here):

```
import BreezySwing.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ButtonTest extends GBFrame {
    private JButton xobutton;
    public ButtonTest()
{
    xobutton = addButton ("[ ]", 1,1,1,1);
}
    public void clientSaidXO(String xo)
    {
        System.out.println(xo);
        xobutton.setText(xo);
    }
public void buttonClicked (JButton buttonObj)
{   
            if(buttonObj == xobutton)
            {       

            }
}

public void start() {
ButtonTest game = new ButtonTest();
game.setSize(250,100);
game.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

So when the server accepts an X or an O from the client it calls the method like this:

```
ButtonTest.clientSaidXO(input);
```

Input is the X or O the client sent.
At first I thought my problem was that I wasn't receiving input from the client correctly, but I was because when I added the print statement in the clientSaidXO method it printed the clients input correctly. Meaning everything is working besides the setText on xobutton. Any kind of insight on how to fix this will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: please show your `addButton()` method.

Comment: BreezySwing handles addButton() in the constructor. xobutton = addButton ("[ ]", 1,1,1,1);